# RoboCopy "Access Denied" Does not return failure

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I have a powershell script to copy files from one computer to another UNC, using robocopy. Recently, it was run with a new user account, and got an Access Denied on the target.
The retry limit was set to 10, so it failed out at that point.
The problem is that the returns of the command do not show that there was a failure, and the exit code was 0, so the failure was not caught.
Full logs below. You can see the options used at the top : (only server names changed)
(
The last line is from the PS command

Write-Host "Robocopy.exe completed with code $lastexitcode")

```
[18:54:04][Step 1/1]   Started : Monday, October 8, 2018 6:54:04 PM
[18:54:04][Step 1/1]    Source : C:\Source
[18:54:04][Step 1/1]      Dest : \\Server\Target
[18:54:04][Step 1/1] 
[18:54:04][Step 1/1]     Files : *.*
[18:54:04][Step 1/1]        
[18:54:04][Step 1/1]   Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /NP /R:2 /W:30 
[18:54:04][Step 1/1] 
[18:54:04][Step 1/1] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[18:54:04][Step 1/1] 
[18:54:06][Step 1/1]                     438    C:\Source
[18:54:06][Step 1/1] 2018/10/08 18:54:06 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Accessing Destination Directory \\Server\Target
[18:54:06][Step 1/1] Access is denied.
[18:54:06][Step 1/1] 
[18:54:38][Step 1/1] Waiting 30 seconds... Retrying...
[18:54:38][Step 1/1] 2018/10/08 18:54:38 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Accessing Destination Directory \\Server\Target
[18:54:38][Step 1/1] Access is denied.
[18:54:38][Step 1/1] 
[18:55:10][Step 1/1] Waiting 30 seconds... Retrying...
[18:55:10][Step 1/1] 2018/10/08 18:55:10 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Accessing Destination Directory \\Server\Target
[18:55:10][Step 1/1] Access is denied.
[18:55:10][Step 1/1] 
[18:55:10][Step 1/1] 
[18:55:10][Step 1/1] ERROR: RETRY LIMIT EXCEEDED.
[18:55:10][Step 1/1] 
[18:55:10][Step 1/1] 
[18:55:10][Step 1/1] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[18:55:10][Step 1/1] 
[18:55:10][Step 1/1]                Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
[18:55:10][Step 1/1]     Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
[18:55:10][Step 1/1]    Files :         0         0         0         0         0         0
[18:55:10][Step 1/1]    Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0         0
[18:55:10][Step 1/1]    Times :   0:01:06   0:00:00                       0:01:00   0:00:06
[18:55:10][Step 1/1]    Ended : Monday, October 8, 2018 6:55:10 PM
[18:55:10][Step 1/1] 
[18:55:10][Step 1/1] Robocopy.exe completed with code 0
```

My only hunch even at this point is that there is something strange about the specific error "Accessing Destination Directory". When I try a test simply removing file permissions, I get the error

```
14:08:15 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying File
```

and robocopy correctly returns exit code 8, with FAILED count = 1.

TIA

JS

Comment: But robocopy _didn't_ fail; it completed (it continued on past the "access denied" messages). The [robocopy documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) does not list a specific exit code for what you want. You will need to write out the log file and examine it afterwards to determine whether your condition occurred.

Comment: If robocopy encounters a different error, normally  it does fail. E:G:

Comment: If robocopy encounters a different error, normally  it does fail. E:G: 
remove ALL  inheritedd permissions from c:\temp\target.
this command:   
    robocopy.exe  C:\temp\Source C:\temp\target /e /purge /r:2 /w:
    write-host "exit code : $lastexitcode"
 
returns this :
                Older                      3        Fiel.txt
    2018/10/10 10:46:00 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying File C:\temp\Source\Fiel.txt
    Access is denied.
    
    ERROR: RETRY LIMIT EXCEEDED.
    
    exit code : 8

Comment: The point is that robocopy's behavior is what it is; you won't be able to change that. If it's not catching the error you want, I'd recommend creating a log file (or trapping stdout, as the answer noted) and checking for errors that way.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Sounds like you're justifying a bug in Robocopy. The documentation says: "8  Several files did not copy." - that's exactly what you would expect if no file was copied.

Comment: Unfortunately, being annoyed by, or disagreeing with, the behavior of the tool doesn't change the behavior of the tool. If you don't like how the tool behaves, it's pointless to complain about it here because 1) I didn't write it and 2) I think it unlikely that the person or persons that did write the tool will change it based on a complaint here.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this AND realize it is from 2018 - but I felt I needed to answer. This will probably get zero votes - but here goes:

1. First, you should (if you haven't already) download the Windows version of the Linux/Unix commands like "grep". Grep is very powerful and makes life easy.

NOTE : Because Windows now contains a GREP function - you will probably have to rename the unix command from "grep" to "fgrep" or maybe "ugrep" - at least I had to do so.

2. You probably need to use (or should use) the "/log:<logfile>" and "/tee" options. The /log option obviously lets you make a log file but the /tee allows you to see, on your screen, the log file. Both are nice options to use.

Once robocopy has finished - you can then use grep.

Ok - so robocopy has finished. Then you can just type:

C:>fgrep -i " error "

This should then give you every line in the log file which has the word ERROR surrounded by spaces. There is also an option to list which line the message is on like so:

C:>fgrep -in " error "

And here is an example:

D:>fgrep -in " error " robocopy.log

```
17:2022/02/26 15:23:22 ERROR 32 (0x00000020) Copying NTFS Security to Destination File C:\DumpStack.log.tmp
21:2022/02/26 15:23:22 ERROR 32 (0x00000020) Copying NTFS Security to Destination File C:\hiberfil.sys
25:2022/02/26 15:23:22 ERROR 32 (0x00000020) Copying NTFS Security to Destination File C:\pagefile.sys
29:2022/02/26 15:23:22 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Copying NTFS Security to Destination File C:\RAMDisk.img
33:2022/02/26 15:23:22 ERROR 32 (0x00000020) Copying NTFS Security to Destination File C:\swapfile.sys
39:2022/02/26 15:23:24 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination File C:\System Volume Information\1{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
43:2022/02/26 15:23:24 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Copying NTFS Security to Destination File C:\System Volume Information\IndexerVolumeGuid
47:2022/02/26 15:23:24 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Copying NTFS Security to Destination File C:\System Volume Information\ISwift3.dat
51:2022/02/26 15:23:24 ERROR 32 (0x00000020) Copying NTFS Security to Destination File C:\System Volume Information\klBackupDepository.dat
55:2022/02/26 15:23:24 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Copying NTFS Security to Destination File C:\System Volume Information\kliddb.dat
59:2022/02/26 15:23:24 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Copying NTFS Security to Destination File C:\System Volume Information\klmeta.dat
63:2022/02/26 15:23:24 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Copying NTFS Security to Destination File C:\System Volume Information\klobjdb.dat
67:2022/02/26 15:23:24 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Copying NTFS Security to Destination File C:\System Volume Information\MountPointManagerRemoteDatabase
72:2022/02/26 15:23:24 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Copying NTFS Security to Destination File C:\System Volume Information\WPSettings.dat
```

Comment: There's no need for an external utility. Just use PowerShell and `Select-String`.

Comment: I don't use PowerShell. Sorry - a die hard CMD person. :-)

Comment: I would say it's time to switch.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to avoid Robocopy or ignore its error handling and just compare the directories after the run. As soon as they don't match, something will probably have gone wrong.

Comment: I agree. Use KeyPass. Free, you can modify what it does by adding in anything you need (if your program) and you can do 90% of what Robocopy does. I have (as of yet) to find a plugin that works with Windows programs to fill in usernames and passwords - but then - I mainly use it with web pages. So your mileage my vary.

Comment: @Mark Manning I don't know how KeyPass ist connected to the topic. :) I would just use normal "copy"  and "dir". I can't see how KeyPass adds something useful to PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

robocopy is a cmd executable, and will not return a $false to powershell, if that's what you're looking for. a good example is the ping command always returns an exit code of 0.  You'll need to utilize a powershell command. copy-item is a good start.

If you must MUST use robocopy, then you could put it into a variable, and have the response checked for "access denied" etc.. in the string.
not sure what your code is, or what you're copying... but an idea...

```
$temp = robocopy *.* /s... etc...
if ($temp -match "Access is denied"){"Robocopy failed due to a denial of access"}
```

Comment: No, it returns an exit code, which is accessible in powershell via the $lastExitCode built-in. :

Comment: you can run an if check on the $lastexitcode but if it exit's the same whether or not it fails, then you'll have to do an output parsing trick. CMD.exe just output text. and can cause a lot of these kinds of issues when it comes to powershell error checking.